# How to properly install PlayOnLinux, all the drivers, etc?

Tags: drivers, wine, games, playonlinux

I am (re)installing Ubuntu 12.04 now, and I'd like to ask what things I have to install to properly run games with PlayOnLinux? I mean do I need to install some kind of graphics driver, or DirectX, .NET, etc? Does it come with Wine? How do I patch the games and how do I install the latest PunkBuster for example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlayOnLinux allows you to easily install and use applications and games that run under Windows.  To install PlayOnLinux just type it in the search box at the Ubuntu Software Center, and click on install.

[image]

The first time you run it, PlayOnLinux will download application updates it needs.  Once it’s finished updating, you can install a Windows application by clicking on install, and then by searching for the application, or by selecting the category on top or by choosing unlisted application. Click on the desired application, providing the you have the application to install.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install such things, just be sure that you have installed your `graphic driver`, `playonlinux` or `wine` include everything you need. Play onlinux has just some scripts to configure your games installation.